# Android Studio - Database inspector is not showing any process

Tags: android, android-studio, sqldelight, database-inspector

I have an android project with SQLDelight database but i'm facing an issue that the process is not showing under the Database Inspector after i run the app on any device or emulator (i.e emulator Pixel 4, API 28).
Note that in the logcat, the emulator and the process and logs are showing well, and the same project is showing the process for the others.
i tried invalidate cache and restart, and it is still the same.
My android studio version is: 4.2.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that persists in the latest Andriod Bumblebee as well

1. Check if your queries are actually working
2. Click Invalidate Caches and Restart and select `Just Restart'
3. Close the project from File>Close Project and open again
4. Try updating or running the project in canary Andriod Studio

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a physical device. Restarting my device worked for me.